# method that returns the sum of the odd integers from 1 to n (inclusive)?

Tags: algorithm

This is what I have got but it doesn't work. When I try to compile I get this error message:

> `int result = 0;`
>   `^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`
>   Unreachable code

My code:

```
public int sumOfOddIntegers (int n) {

    if(n < 1);
    return 0;

    int result = 0;
    for(int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if(i % 2 != 0) {
            result = result + i;
       }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You have to use proper tags (e.g. the **language** you are using), if you want this question to get any attention. `methods` is a useless tag on its own.

Comment: Saying something "doesn't work" isn't helpful. What does it output? What are you expecting it to output?

Comment: What precisely "doesn't work"?

Comment: You should probably change "i = n-1" to "i = n".

Comment: Always use curly braces for conditions to avoid such mistakes

Comment: Why not use the math formula that gives you directly the sum? `SUM(1+3+5+...+n) = λ^2` where `λ=trunc((n+1)/2)`

Comment: Semicolon after the first if! It means that the `return 0` always happens, thus preventing anything else after it from getting run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(n < 1);
    return 0;
```

is equivalent to :

```
if(n < 1) {
}

return 0;
```

It shoud be replaced by :

```
if(n < 1)
    return 0;
```

or (the right way)

```
if(n < 1) {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The statement:

```
if(n < 1);
```

Is a no op because of the semi-colon. The comparison is evaluated, and nothing is done, whatever the result of the comparison is.

Then, the next line is executed, which returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

`if(n < 1);` is your problem. The rest of the code is unreachable beacuse the following `return'` is always exectued.

Remove the `;` after `if(n < 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the semi colon on your if statement is the problem. Personally however I would just do it like this:

```
public int sumOfOddIntegers (int n) 
{
    int result = 0;

    if(n < 1)
        return result;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i += 2)
    {
        result += i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This way you can halve the number of iterations. We know every other number is odd, so why even bother iterating the even ones and checking if they're odd when we know they're not?

Comment: If you go for optimising, why not `int result = (n+1)/2; return result*result;` (after checking `n < 0`)?

Comment: Sure, that works too, I didn't want to stray too far into the realm of optimisation and scare Ali off too much though!

Comment: I bet every person reading this except the OP cringed when they saw how he was generating the odd integers. He won't get full marks for his implementation, even without the semicolon. Yours demonstrates a firm grasp of the C "for" and "return" constructs, simple Boolean logic, and use of a variable to accumulate a total. I'm sure yours would get 5/5.

Answer (score 0):

the sequence is a arithmetic progression with common difference of 2.
so its sum would be given by formula :

sum =  n/2(2a+(n-1)d

where n = Math.ceil(k); where k is the given number.
and d = 2, a=1

```
public int sumOfOddIntegers (int n) {         

if(n < 1);
return 0;

int totalNumber = Math.ceil(n/2);         

return  (totalNumber/2)*(2 + (totalNumber-1)*2);
```

`